# Python 2.6: proper usage of unittest.TestSuite

Tags: python, unit-testing

Using Python 2.6, I have a very simple test in a python file in a directory:

```
#mytest.py
import unittest

class BasicTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_ok(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(BasicTests)
```

I change into the directory and run `python -m unittest mytest.suite` and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/runpy.py", line 122, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/runpy.py", line 34, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 875, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 816, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 843, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 849, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 613, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 598, in loadTestsFromName
    test = obj()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/unittest.py", line 464, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: run() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I've tried several variations (such as `unittest.makeSuite` and `unittest.LoadTestFromNames`) but they all give me the same basic error. What am I missing? I keep [reading the documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/unittest.html) and I seem to be following the spec.

Comment: Just a guess: does it need another argument at the command line?

Comment: You could avoid creating test suites by hand by using a test runner such as provided by `unittest2`, `nose`, `py.text`.

Comment: Frustrating that you need to download a package to do something as simple as get a decent test runner for python even with editions as new as 2.6.  :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't usually work with `unittest` on the command line, but have my own test running scripts.

You need to add a function `suite` to the module

```
def suite():
    return unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(BasicTests)
```

and then call it like `python -m unittest mytest.suite`. But then I run into the following problem:

```
TypeError: calling <function suite at 0x00C1FB70> returned <unittest.TestSuite tests=[<mysite.BasicTests testMethod=test_ok>]>, not a test
```

which happens because `unittest` uses something like `isinstance(mytest.suite(), TestSuite)` but through executing with `-m`, you get two different versions of the `TestSuite` class (one is `__main__.TestSuite`, the other is `unittest.TestSuite`), so `isinstance` returns false.

To me, this looks like a bug. Patching `unittest.py` by inserting `from unittest import TestSuite, TestCase` at the beginning of `loadTestsFromName` solves the `isinstance` problem. Sorry I can't give you the "*correct*" solution (if there is one).

Comment: I've done some digging through the source and it appears to be a bug in my distribution's build of python 2.6. When I execute under 2.7, the problem goes away. Ugh!

Comment: @dave: Just checked that. They added a special `__main__.py` file there which effectively works like my workaround. Still wondering whether there is a good solution for Python 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: it looks like what I have above is in fact, correct. When I installed a copy of Python 2.7, everything worked fine. I dug through the `unittest.py` source code and found that this line of code was not working the way one would expect:

```
    elif isinstance(obj, TestSuite):
        return obj
    elif hasattr(obj, '__call__'):
        test = obj()
```

The first `elif` condition is failing, and thus it falls down into the one after where the exception is raised. I'm still not sure how that could even remotely happen — maybe a bad compilation — but I've gone ahead and [filed a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.6/+bug/726257) with the provider.

Comment: Instead of "for whatever reason", you could have simply quoted my answer in which I clearly described why exactly it fails. And please use Python's bug tracker next time, Launchpad is meant for the Ubuntu package, not for upstream.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

**mytest.py:**

```
import unittest

class BasicTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_ok(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.sys.argv.insert(1,'--verbose')
    unittest.main(argv = unittest.sys.argv)
```

Then,

```
% python mytest.py
```

runs all tests in all subclasses of `TestCase`, and

```
% python mytest.py BasicTests.test_ok
```

runs just `test_ok`. This second form of the command is useful when you know there is a problem with one test and don't wish to run through every test.

Comment: Yes, this is great. But why can't I just use unittest.main(argv = '-v'), is it a bug?

Comment: Is there some kind of function that you can add several TestCase classes to a runner? like

unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCases([TestCases])?

Comment: @jaimechen: Two good questions. Unfortunately, my answer to both is... I don't know. Please make each a new question so others may be able to answer them.