# How to run Python's unittest.TestSuite() with -v flag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am using:

- Python 3.6.1
- vanilla [unittest framework](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html)

I am aware that [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [py.test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) provide much more possibilities, than plain unittest. Though, the objective here is to stick with the current environment.

---

My `suite.py` file, which resides in `/tests` directory, looks like this:

```python
import unittest

loader = unittest.TestLoader()
suite = loader.discover('.')

runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(suite)
```

I run it (from project's root) this way:

```
python -m unittest tests/suite.py
```

This runs all the [`TestCase`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)s from `/tests` directory and produces output (in console) like this:

```
......ss....s............s.....s.s....s.....................s....ss.....s......s......s..........s...........s.....s.....s....s
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 117 tests in 54.110s

OK (skipped=13)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

---

The questions are:

1. What the second part of the output

   ```
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

   OK
   ```

   that is, is referring to (and why is it there)?
2. How do I obtain detailed output from running a suite (i.e. status of every test, same as when running `python -m unittest -v` from the project's root)? I have tried `python -m unittest -v tests/suite.py`, but it doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, [as is it sometimes happens](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), I figured out an answer to my own question.It was an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5136417/8554766), actually, that gave me an idea on what I was missing.

---

The answers, I have discovered, are:

1. Second part of console output:

   ```
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

   OK
   ```

   is referring to tests in the current module (i.e. file that was ran), in this case — `suite.py`. As the file itself contains no `TestCase`s, thus the output is 'blank' (it can be easily verified: create an empty file `test.py`, then launch it as `python -m unittest tests/test.py` — you will see the exactly same output as above).
2. In order to obtain detailed output from the `TestSuite` run — creation of the `TestSuite` must be wrapped in a method (which returns the created `TestSuite`) and then not a module, but a method must be passed to `python -m unittest -v`.

   So, `suite.py` must be changed to:

   ```
   import unittest

   def suite():
       loader = unittest.TestLoader()
       suite = loader.discover('.')
       return suite
   ```

   And then it should be launched via `python -m unittest -v tests.suite.suite`, this gives detailed status on each test and avoids unnecessary `... Ran 0 tests in 0.000s ...` output.